# Does anyone make Google Chrome Themes?

Tags: windows, ubuntu, google-chrome

I'm just wondering if there are any unofficial Google Chrome Themes that I can easily install (eg. don't have to copy a .dll to the themes folder)?

I would like to be able to click apply theme (just like you can on Google's Official Themes page). Do any exist?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I just wanted to update this:** Google has now added about **30** new themes to their page, under the artist tab. Some are really good, some aren't but at least we have more choices.

Answer (score 3):

Check out the documentation on Google Code on [Themes for Chrome](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/themes.html).

> A theme is a special kind of extension that changes the way the browser looks. Themes are [packaged](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/packaging.html) like regular extensions, but they don't contain JavaScript or HTML code.

Basically, you create a `manifest.json` file, which contains all the data and information required for your theme (such as which images are used for which component of the GUI). Here's an example:

> ```
> {
>   "version": "2.6",
>   "name": "camo theme",
>   "theme": {
>     "images" : {
>       "theme_frame" : "images/theme_frame_camo.png",
>       "theme_frame_overlay" : "images/theme_frame_stripe.png",
>       "theme_toolbar" : "images/theme_toolbar_camo.png",
>       "theme_ntp_background" : "images/theme_ntp_background_norepeat.png",
>       "theme_ntp_attribution" : "images/attribution.png"
>     },
>     "colors" : {
>        "frame" : [71, 105, 91],
>       "toolbar" : [207, 221, 192],
>       "ntp_text" : [20, 40, 0],
>       "ntp_link" : [36, 70, 0],
>       "ntp_section" : [207, 221, 192],
>       "button_background" : [255, 255, 255]
>     },
>     "tints" : {
>       "buttons" : [0.33, 0.5, 0.47]
>     },
>     "properties" : {
>       "ntp_background_alignment" : "bottom"
>     }
>   }
> }
> ```

Once you have finished, packaging it up is just as simple as going to `chrome://extensions` in the address bar in Chrome, and click the Pack extension button. For more details, check out [Packaging](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/packaging.html) in the Chrome documentation

Comment: I had seen that before. It looks really promising, the only problem for me is that I suck at making nice looking themes. Mine usually just suck. I would rather leave theming to the pro's. I still upvoted you though, because maybe someone will find this link and make a really cool theme. ;-)